# Change style.display on multiple objects through one button JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, styles, event-listener

im trying to change the display attribute of multiple objects through one button, using event listener. It works fine if I just want to change the display on one object at a time but not all three..

any ideas?

http://jsfiddle.net/rn9vrwyg/

```
var ruta1 = document.getElementById('ruta1')
var ruta2 = document.getElementById('ruta2')
var ruta3 = document.getElementById('ruta3')

document.getElementById('knapp1').addEventListener("click", function(){
ruta1.style.display = "block";
ruta2.style.display = "none";
ruta3.style.display = "none";

});

document.getElementById('knapp2').addEventListener("click", function(){
ruta2.style.display = "block";  
ruta1.style.display = "none";
ruta3.style.display = "none";

});

document.getElementById('knapp3').addEventListener("click", function(){
ruta3.style.display = "block";
ruta1.style.display = "none";
ruta2.style.display = "none";


});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div id="ruta1">
      <p>Informationbox #1</p>
    </div>
        <div id="ruta2">
      <p>Informationbox #2</p>
    </div>
        <div id="ruta3">
      <p>Informationbox #3</p>
    </div>
```

These div's and p tags are not closed properly. Close those tags then its working as expected.